# How do I sum two variables together from different datasets in xarray while ensuring only data with the same coordinates and time get summed?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, netcdf, python-xarray

I am currently working with precipitation data, and my goal is two add two different types of precipitation data together to get a result that is in effect, analogous to total precipitation. I am using xarray to manage this multi-dimensional data, and I want to ultimately end up with precipitation data plotted by coordinates on a map, with the time dimension averaged out. It is important that only data with the same coordinates and time be summed together. The three dimensions of the two variables are longitude, latitude, and time. Both variables have the same units. The two variables are contained within two separate datasets, and I want to end up with a single data array with the dimensions longitude, latitude, and time and the variable total precipitation. How would I go about summing these two data with respect to coordinates and time?

Very sorry if the context or question is jumbled and doesn't make sense, I am new to python and even newer to xarray. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have two data sets and want to determine the sum of precipitation for each grid cell avergaged over the entire time to plot this?

### Case 1

Assuming that your two data sets have the same dimension scales, it works like this
(In my example I use temperature data and calculate the difference. You can just replace the "-" with a "+" to get the sum):

```
import xarray as xr, numpy as np
import matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.mpl.ticker as cticker # to have ticks
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature #coastlines

ds_1 = xr.open_dataset("/PATH2yourFile/dataset1.nc")
ds_2 = xr.open_dataset("/PATH2yourFile/dataset2.nc")

res = ds_1['tsurf'].mean('time') - ds_2['tsurf'].mean('time')
```

Plotting:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
res.plot.contourf(cmap="Spectral_r", transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), levels=143)
ax.set_title("difference of mean temperatures", fontsize=18)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(25,75,10)); plt.xticks(fontsize=16)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-45,65,15)); plt.yticks(fontsize=16)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(cticker.LatitudeFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(cticker.LongitudeFormatter())
ax.set_ylabel("latitude", fontsize=16)
ax.set_xlabel("longitude", fontsize=16)
ax.coastlines()
```

[image: Plot]

If you want to save the result:

```
res.to_netcdf("result.nc")
```

### Case 2

If your datasets have different scales, than you can use [cdo](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo) to get the sum for each grid cell like this:

```
cdo add -selvar,pr dataset1.nc -selvar,pr dataset2.nc pr_sum.nc
```

and then calculate the overall mean:

```
cdo timmean -selvar,pr pr_sum.nc pr_timmean.nc
```

After that you can simply load it into python with xarray and plot it as described above.